# How to print the values and value's original line in perl?

Tags: perl

My file like this

```
(*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*AP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*TP*GP*GP  
(*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*AP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*TP*GP*GP  
(*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*CP*TP*TP*TP*TP*AP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*TP*GP*GP  
(*UP*CP*AP*GP*CP*CP*AP*CP*UP*UP*UP*UP*UP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*AP  
(*UP*CP*AP*GP*CP*CP*AP*CP*UP*UP*UP*UP*UP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*AP  
(*UP*CP*AP*GP*CP*CP*AP*CP*UP*UP*UP*UP*UP*AP*AP*AP*AP*GP*AP  
values 290   MR1   1  1.000000  0.000000  
values 290   MR2   1  0.000000  1.000000 
values 290   MR3   1  0.000000  0.000000  
values 290   MR1   2 -1.000000  0.000000  
values 290   MR2   2  0.000000 -1.000000 
values 290   MR3   2  0.000000  0.000000 
values 290   MR1   3 -1.000000  0.000000 
SEE FOR THE AUTHOR PROVIDED AND/OR PROGRAM GENERATED ASSEMBLY INFORMATION.                 
THIS ENTRY. THE REMARK MAY ALSO PROVIDE INFORMATION ON               
BURIED SURFACE AREA.                                                                                                                     
350 COMPLETE MULTIMER REPRESENTING THE KNOWN           
350 BIOLOGICALLY SIGNIFICANT OLIGOMERIZATION STATE OF THE                
350 GENERATED BY APPLYING BIOMT TRANSFORMATIONS          
350 GIVEN BELOW.  BOTH NON-CRYSTALLOGRAPHIC AND                          
350 OPERATIONS ARE GIVEN.                               
350                                                                      
350 BIOMOLECULE: 1                                                       
350 AUTHOR DETERMINED BIOLOGICAL UNIT    
VALUES    944  CA  SER A 124      19.929  15.508  41.001  1.00 27.16           C  
VALUES    945  C   SER A 124      18.528  15.865  41.525  1.00 27.86           C  
VALUES    946  O   SER A 124      18.305  16.949  42.074  1.00 29.52           O  
VALUES    947  CB  SER A 124      20.209  16.197  39.656  1.00 27.72           C  
VALUES    948  OG  SER A 124      19.168  16.143  38.688  1.00 29.83           O  
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N  
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C
```

my script below

```
use warnings;
use strict;
print "Enter the filename >> ";
chomp(my $s = <>);
die "error openng file" unless (open('i',"$s"));
my @a=<i>;
my @grep = grep{s/^VALUES.*\w{3}\s\w//g} @a;
my @grep2 = grep{s/^values.*MR\d\s//g} @a;
my @x1; 
my @y1;
my $y;
my $x;
foreach (@grep)
{
    $x = (split)[1],$_;
    $y = (split)[2],$_;
    push (@x1,$x);
    push (@y1,$y);
}
my @x2; 
my @y2;
foreach (@grep2)
{
    $x = (split)[1],$_;
    $y = (split)[2],$_; 
    push (@x2,$x);
    push (@y2,$y);
}
my @x;
my @y;
my @tot;
my $i; my $j;
for ($i=0 ; $i<@x1 ; $i++)
{
    for ($j=0 ; $j<@x2 ; $j++)
    {
        my $m = $x1[$i] - $x2[$j];
        my $v = $m/2;
        push (@x , $v);
     }
 }

for ($i=0 ; $i<@y1 ; $i++)
{
    for ($j=0 ; $j<@y2 ; $j++)
    {
        my $m = $y1[$i] - $y2[$j];
        my $v = $m/2;
        push (@y,$v);
     }
}
for ($i=0 ; $i< scalar @x ; $i++)
{
    my $total = $x[$i] + $y[$i];
    print "$total\n";
    push (@tot,$total);
} 
#Below script i get confused
for(@grep)
{
    my @mk = @tot <='17';
    print "$_ \tWHICH ANSWER IS >> @mk\n";
}
```

Mathematical function used to 'values' and 'VALUES'. I get confused at how to print the values lessthan '17' which lines are print from the 'VALUES'. How i do it?

```
#I expect output is
VALUES    945  C   SER A 124      18.528  15.865  41.525  1.00 27.86           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.6965                          
VALUES    945  C   SER A 124      18.528  15.865  41.525  1.00 27.86           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.6965
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.756
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.756
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.256
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.256
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.756
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.256
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.756
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.187 
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.187 
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.687 
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.187
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.187
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 15.687
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.187
```

And how avoid the 'Useless use of a variable in void context' error. in some lines

Comment: Are there always the same number of `values` as there are `VALUES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have yourself a little tied up here. Your main problem (and what took me so long to work out what it is you were aiming for) is that you create elements for `@x` and `@y` for *every combination* of `@grep` and `@grep2` instead of just pairing them up one for one

I take that back. On reflection, the *biggest* problem to understanding and fixing your code is your dreadful choice of variable names! I don't know what to call the data labelled `VALUES` and `values` so I have just used arrays `@VALUES` and `@values`, but you should rename them appropriately

I have come up with this program which does what I think you want. It produces only three output records which is far smaller than your example required output, but I think that output corresponds to a bigger input file? You should show the output you expected *for the example input*, otherwise we have no way of testing our solutions

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

print "Enter the filename: ";
chomp(my $filename = <>);
open my $in_fh, '<', $filename;

my (@VALUES, @values);

while (<$in_fh>) {
  chomp;
  if ( /^values/ ) {
    push @values, [ $_, (split)[4,5] ];
  }
  elsif ( /^VALUES/ ) {
    push @VALUES, [ $_, (split)[6,7] ];
  }
}

for my $i (0 .. $#VALUES) {

  my $total;
  for my $j (1, 2) {
    $total += ( $VALUES[$i][$j] - $values[$i][$j] ) / 2;
  }

  if ($total <= 17.0) {
    printf "%s  WHICH ANSWER IS >> %s\n", $VALUES[$i][0], $total;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
VALUES    945  C   SER A 124      18.528  15.865  41.525  1.00 27.86           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.6965
VALUES    949  N   LYS A 125      17.556  14.956  41.380  1.00 26.42           N    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.256
VALUES    950  CA  LYS A 125      16.202  15.172  41.869  1.00 26.36           C    WHICH ANSWER IS >> 16.187
```

Comment: The digits of 'VALUES(@VALUES)' some time present without space. so how can use the substr in the script

Comment: @user3710242: I can't help you without seeing your input data. Please post examples of *all* the data formats you expect to see

Comment: @user3710242: Please also tell me what you would call the data lines starting `VALUES` and those starting `values`? What do they *mean* to you?

Comment: @user3710242: Thank you, but please edit your question to include any additional information. It is impossible to post data reliably in comments. If you are asking for something different then you should open a new question. Please remember that your question will be read by others with a similar problem, and you should do your best to make it useful to others

Comment: sir i posted new question 'How to print the values and with its original line in perl?' topic

Answer (score 1):

The following line and others like it are giving you the `Useless use of a variable in void context` message:

```
$x = (split)[1],$_;
```

Your trailing `,$_` is meaningless.  You want:

```
$x = (split)[1];
```

And if you want to be clearer still about your intent, I'd combine the two lines assigning `$x` and `$y`:

```
(undef, $x, $y) = split;
```

Comment: Actually, I believe you wouldn't have got yourself into that position in the first place: via a `grep` with a block that lops off all but one of the unwanted fields from the beginning of each record!